# Swift - Realm how to query by boolean

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
let query : Query = Query().equal(key: "userId", value: userId)
        .and()
        .equal(key: "verified", value: true)

        self.findAllByQuery(query: query, completion: completion)
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason: 'Expected object of type bool for property 'verified' on object of type 'Profile', but received: true'

Comment: Why does this have both swift and objective-c tags? Its either one or the other, which is it?

Comment: What library are you using? `Query` / `findAllByQuery` aren't part of Realm.

Comment: Be sure to ADD MORE CODE to your question, or it will be closed.  Make your question clearer.